# No rule to make target `glfw3.dll'

Tags: c++, netbeans, glfw

I'm trying to build a simple vulkan example with Netbeans 8.0.2 using MinGW64 5.3.0. But for some reason, it doesn't seem to want to find the glf3.dll file even though the dependency locations and file names have been specified in the linker options.

Error message:

```
C:\Tools\MinGW\msys\1.0\bin\make.exe -f Makefile CONF=Debug
"/C/Tools/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make.exe[1]: Entering directory `/c/Users/gkovalechyn/Documents/NetBeansProjects/VulkanTests'
"/C/Tools/MinGW/msys/1.0/bin/make.exe"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/MinGW_64-Windows/vulkantests.exe
make.exe[2]: Entering directory `/c/Users/gkovalechyn/Documents/NetBeansProjects/VulkanTests'
mkdir -p build/Debug/MinGW_64-Windows
rm -f "build/Debug/MinGW_64-Windows/main.o.d"
g++ -m64 -std=c++11   -c -g -I../../../../../Libraries/glm -I../../../../../Libraries/glfw-3.2.bin.WIN64/include -I../../../../../Tools/VulkanSDK/1.0.17.0/Include -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/MinGW_64-Windows/main.o.d" -o build/Debug/MinGW_64-Windows/main.o main.cpp
make.exe[2]: *** No rule to make target `glfw3.dll', needed by `dist/Debug/MinGW_64-Windows/vulkantests.exe'.  Stop.
make.exe[2]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/gkovalechyn/Documents/NetBeansProjects/VulkanTests'
make.exe[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make.exe[1]: Leaving directory `/c/Users/gkovalechyn/Documents/NetBeansProjects/VulkanTests'
make.exe": *** [.build-impl] Error 2
```

Linker settings:

[image: Linker settings]

Proof that the DLL exists in that folder:

[image: Proof]

Comment: Try clean all and rebuild.

Comment: I've tried that already, still the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it myself. I had to tell Netbeans the exact path to the libraries instead of adding them as additional dependencies.

So basically, go to the project properties, Build -> Linker -> Libraries. From there add the libraries FILES, not the library and it should work.